# IsEmpty or IsNull or IsNothing?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Can someone help me determine which I should be using?

Here is the situation - I am pulling a value from a column in the Data Table.  If there is anything in that column, I set the data to a variable and take an action.  If the column is blank, I want to skip that.

I am confused as to which IsWHATEVER statement would be best.  For Example:

```
If IsEmpty(Datatable.Value("M4","Data_Entry"))=False Then
```

OR

```
If IsNull(Datatable.Value("M4","Data_Entry"))=False Then
```

OR

```
If IsNothing(Datatable.Value("M4","Data_Entry"))=False Then
```

Suggestions?

Comment: A quick reference to W3School would have helped. http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_keywords.asp

Comment: Thanks!  The sites I had checked made it more confusing than clear.

Comment: Hmm ... IsNull would be your safest bet

Comment: IsNothing() does not exist. Change to

If Not Datatable.Value("M4","Data_Entry") Is Nothing Then ...

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried all of your options and found this to be the most correct:

```
If (DataTable.Value("M4","Global") <> "") Then
```

Your original options will not work on QTP Datatables as these are for uninitialised objects or variables. However, in QTP as soon as you create a parameter in the Datatable the first value gets initialised as *blank* (not to be confused with *empty*).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with shreyansp.. The 3 options are for variables and objects

You could also use the below expression

```
If len(trim(DataTable.Value("M4","Global"))>0 Then
   'Do code here
End If
```